# Can I use live yoghurt to kick-start fermentation?

Tags: meat, fermentation, yogurt, raw-meat, curing

I am making a type of fermented sausage from the Faroe Islands. The recipe says to keep them above 20 degrees (Celsius) for the first 12 hours, to make sure the lactobacilli multiply enough to initiate lactic acid fermentation.

Included in the sausage mix is 500ml of milk. Would replacing some of this with live yoghurt help to ensure a good colony of lactobacillus is present, thus reducing the risk of the fermentation not starting quickly enough?

And could I extend this to other lactic acid fermentation recipes e.g. sauerkraut?

Comment: Wow, quite esoteric. I don't recall many fermented meat Q's here. I hope someone can help.

Comment: @Paulb Obscurity is the spice of life ;)

Comment: Lactic bacteria are not particularly associated with milk. Sure, there are ones that like milk, but the things are everywhere, as explified by sauerkraut, which is a lactic fermentation and has no milk product anywhere near it (except for recipies by people that fail to "get that" concept - the strains that would do well in milk are not the same that would do well in cabbage.) So That's one thing. The bacteria predominant in yogurt are *Streptococcus thermophilus* and *Lactobacillus delbrueckii subsp. bulgaricus* - doubtful that these are the species you want to promote in sausage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use live yogurt as a starter to ferment yogurt, veggies. However, if you want to make sure to have a lot of Streptococci and Lactobacilli, you can use the probiotics (in dried form) to boost fermentation faster.

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to see if you cannot find a cheese hobby shop that will not sell  you a strain of the bacteria and simply cut out the  middleman. You can inoculate sausage  with bacteria very much like you do with cheese so there really is any need to do the diary.